# tabletop_segmentation in rviz

Tags: ros, kinect, tabletop-object-detector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to see the output of tabletop_segmentation in rviz. Would really appreciate a little help. Nothing fancy - just the plain vanilla segmented point cloud, dont need to recognize objects, etc.

Precise 12.04, Fuerte

Running openni.launch (XBOX 360 Kinect cam), rviz and **tabletop_segmentation.launch**

All I can see in rviz is the point cloud from Kinect. How can I see markers from segmentation like shown in the tutorial for tabletop_object_detector?

Ran rostopic - I can see a published topic: **tabletop_segmentation_markers** - but nothing is being published to it.

Looks like tabletop_segmentation node is not getting data from Kinect. In the startup logs, I can see it using cloud_in:=narrow_stereo_textured/points2. Is that same as Kinect? If not, do I have to remap topics somehow?

Also, Kinect's IR projector lamp does not turn on when I just run tabletop_segmentation - it turns on only when I start rviz - another reason to suspect that I am not hooking things up correctly.

Please help, been trying to get this working for several long days now ...

Thanks!
Greg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63378/tabletop_segmentation-in-rviz/) by [Greg S](https://answers.ros.org/users/4943/greg-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was the setting in tabletop_segmentation.launch

```
...
<arg name="tabletop_segmentation_points_in" default="/camera/depth_registered/points" />
<arg name="tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link" **default="false"** />
...
```

This decouples tabletop segmentation from PR2 coordinate system

Thanks to Matei for pointing it out to me offline!

---

Originally posted by [Greg S](https://answers.ros.org/users/4943/greg-s/) with karma: 36 on 2013-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-12**:
I have the same problem, specially with the kinect not turning on, but when i implement your answer i still get the same problem, do you have any idea why?  Also when you want to see the segmentation in rviz what new display type do you add? Thanks